# MobileMe on iPod

Tags: ipod-touch, mobileme, email

Is it possible to change the default `myname@me.com` address to by `myname@mac.com`?
I'm part of a lot of mailing lists with the "mac.com", but iPod seems to send email with "me.com" ...

Answer (score 1):

If you had @mac.com before and have same name @me.com ->mac.com is aliases of your me.com account
If you have only @me.com account you cannot

Comment: They are aliases indeed. But the Mailing list engines deny my me.com address. That's my problem. I just want to send emails from my iPod with mac.com

Answer (score 1):

If you set up that account with @mac.com in the Apple ID section - it will default to that domain rather than @me.com.